# Extension-methods VS static method resolution - what do I miss in spec?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, format, static-methods

I've added an extension method that is a shortcut to string.Format:

```
public static string Format(this string format, params object[] args)
{
    return String.Format(format, args);
}
```

When I invoke this method like this:

```
"{0}".Format(1);
```

everything works like a charm.
While

```
"{0}".Format("1");
```

does not compile with this error message:

> error CS0176: Member
>   'string.Format(string, params
>   object[])' cannot be accessed with an
>   instance reference; qualify it with a
>   type name instead

I fixed this issue by renaming a method (ooh it was a pain). But why does it happen? I know about extension vs instance priority - but this is not an instance method. And IMO if one path could not be resolved (referencing static method in non-static context) then the other (fully legitimate) should be attempted. What do I miss in spec?

**Update 1** Added  compile error message.

Comment: Whats the compile error message?

Comment: Thanks. I added error message to root question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 7.5.3.1 (function member applicability) says nothing about whether a member is static or not. In other words, the static method `String.Format(String, params Object[] args)` is still *applicable* in your second invocation, even though it won't actually work.

Extension methods are only searched for if no applicable function members are found.

In other words, member lookup is performed on a *type* and a set of arguments (and potentially type arguments). The *validation* of the result of the member lookup is done later, as the final step of section 7.6.5.1.

Comment: If applicable!=compilable - then it's logical. I agree. It would be better if such shortcuts worked, though :).